# Error while installing the package "INLA"

Tags: r, install.packages

R VERSION 3.6.2

```
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"),
   c("Package", "Type")) : 
         cannot open the connection
       In addition: Warning messages:
       1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
         downloaded length 210960384 != reported length 335976807
       2: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
       3: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
         cannot open compressed file 'INLA/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Please add the installation command you have used.

Comment: install.packages("INLA", repos=c(getOption("repos"), INLA="https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable"), dep=TRUE)
install.packages("INLA", repos=c(getOption("repos"), INLA="https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/testing"), dep=TRUE)

Comment: i also try this:  install.packages("INLA", repos="http://www.math.ntnu.no/inla/R/testing")

Answer (score 2):

I personally find one thing useful here. Since R-studio automatically set timeout to be 60s. If the package is relatively large (like 80M), it need to download for like 100s, yet the download thread stops at 60s, causing the error length 210960384 != reported length 335976807. Change the default download time longer would help with this issue in general.

```
# 100s
options(timeout=100)
# 200s
options(timeout=200)
# 1000s
options(timeout=1000)
```